# Dynamic VRP with Pickup (from one or few places) and Delivery

Tags: optimization, routes, optaplanner, traveling-salesman, jsprit

The problem I'm facing is:

- pickups goods from many places, not from depots.
- there is no main/depot place. All drivers may start driving wherever they want.
- dynamically adding goods locations and their destinations (while drivers are on the road).
- There could be only one driver to reduce the complexity of the problem.

Do you know any implementations to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an implementation with OptaPlanner.](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment)